# Поиск Телеграм каналов по названию

Tags: python, telegram

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать **поиск Каналов (в Телеграм) по их Названию** на языке программирования **PYTHON**

Например:
Посылая запрос "**linux**" получить список аккаунтов у которых в **Названии / @КороткомИмени** есть это слово

***Важно***, чтобы **поиск был глобальным**, и я **получал Каналы те, на которые я не подписан**

К сожалению, в API TELEGRAM я не нашел нужного метода, может есть какие то другие способы получить ссылки на Каналы, по названию (поиск каналов Телеграм)

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Все ещё надеюсь на ответ..